# Disable Button until multiple Textboxes got Validated

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation

I have a form with over 10 textboxes and 1 button, I would like to disable the button with a realtime validation until all textboxes filled with a 10 or a 13 length numeric value, my code is the following so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each userID As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        AddHandler userID.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateAllFields
    Next userID
End Sub
Private Sub userID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        Else
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Function ValidateAllFields()
    Dim Validation As Boolean = True
    For Each userID As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        Dim e As New System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs
        e.Cancel = False
        Call userID_Validating(userID, e)
        If e.Cancel = True Then Validation = False
    Next userID
    buttonSave.Enabled = Not Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Any(Function(userID) userID.Text.Length <> 10 AndAlso userID.Text.Length <> 13)
    Return Validation
End Function
Private Sub userID_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles _
    user00.Validating, _
    user01.Validating, _
    user02.Validating, _
    user03.Validating, _
    user04.Validating, _
    user05.Validating, _
    user06.Validating, _
    user07.Validating, _
    user07.Validating, _
    user08.Validating, _
    user09.Validating, _
    user10.Validating, _
    user11.Validating
    If Not IsNumeric(sender.Text) OrElse (sender.Text.Length <> 10) AndAlso (sender.Text.Length <> 13) Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(sender, "")
        ErrorProvider2.SetError(sender, "Please enter a valid User ID.")
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(sender, "Valid User ID.")
        ErrorProvider2.SetError(sender, "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks to your help it works as I wanted, but can you help me improve/clean it? I'm still studying vb, I'm open to any suggestion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of error is valid user id?

Comment: the ErrorProvider1 supposed to add a green tick icon to each textbox if the input is correct in this code.

Comment: Are you saying that each of the 10 textboxes must contain a number who's length is 10-13 characters?

Comment: each of the 10 textboxes must contain a number with 10 or 13 length, 11 or 12 length input should be invalid.

Comment: I think for this creating a usercontrol (inheriting from textbox) will be best fit that fires textchange event for all textboxes. Also adding all textboxes in a list will be equally helpful. Try implementing my suggestion. I will not post any code here, I am scared of VB.Net. I am more of C# guy

Comment: @ml87 to get what is written in each textbox you have to rely on the TextChanged event. In my code I am including 3 textboxes performing the actions you want and you might extend it to as many textboxes as you wish. I have updated it right now to accomplish exactly what you are looking for (originally, I understood that the 10 or 13 should be written in the textboxes, not that this was actually the length of the given number).

Comment: So you are using ErrorProvider to say there's no error. You do realise the name errorprovider is a clue right?

Comment: Do you know a better solution to mark the correct inputs with a green tick for a user?

Comment: Yes. Add an image control. Or create a user control with edit and an image. All your problems are around trying to bend error provider (and to some extent Validate to do something other than what it was designed for.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would post a code how would you do it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a code performing the actions you want:

```
Dim done1, done2, done3 As Boolean
Dim targetLength1 As Integer = 10
Dim targetLength2 As Integer = 13
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Try
        If (IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text)) Then
            If (TextBox1.Text.Length = targetLength1 Or TextBox1.Text.Length = targetLength2) Then
                done1 = True
            End If
        End If
        If (done1 And done2 And done3) Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    Try
        If (IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text)) Then
            If (TextBox2.Text.Length = targetLength1 Or TextBox2.Text.Length = targetLength2) Then
                done2 = True
            End If
        End If
        If (done1 And done2 And done3) Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    Try
        If (IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text)) Then
            If (TextBox3.Text.Length = targetLength1 Or TextBox3.Text.Length = targetLength2) Then
                done3 = True
            End If
        End If
        If (done1 And done2 And done3) Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

It accounts just for 3 textboxes (`TextBox1`, `TextBox2` and `TextBox3`) and 1 button (`Button1`) but you can extend the idea to as many textboxes as you wish. It relies on the TextChanged even of each textbox. When the condition is met (given textbox has a number whose length is 10 or 13), the corresponding flag is set to true (e.g., done1 for TextBox1...). When all the flags are true (all the textboxes contain the expected information), the button is disabled.

Comment: thank you for your solution, works great to disable/enable the button, yet i would like to create a common textchange event to check all textboxes in the form and mark with errorprovider for the user if the inputs meets the requirements.

Comment: Each textbox has its own handler/event method. You can automate its treatment but, at the end, you will have to consider as many methods as textboxes.

Comment: i'm thinking about creating a counter that adds/deduct 1 according to each validation, and in the end if the counter is equal to the number of the textboxes then enables the button, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think would better to use TextChanged Event ..

```
Private Sub TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, ....., TextBox10.TextChanged

    Chk4ButtonEnabled()

End Sub

Sub Chk4ButtonEnabled()
Dim s as String

  For Each userID As Control In Me.Controls
      If userID.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
        s = userID.Text
        If Not s.Length = 10 OR Not s.Length = 13 Then
          ErrorProvider1.SetError(userID, "")
          buttonSave.Enabled = False  
        Else
          ErrorProvider1.SetError(userID, "Valid User ID.")
          buttonSave.Enabled = True
        End If
      End If
  Next     

End Sub
```